# Javascript update form element in grandchild window

Tags: javascript, forms, frames

I'm aware of how to edit a form via javascript so using something like this.

```
document.formname.fieldname.value
```

However im now having another issue, I have a frame which contains another frame inside.

So the first is A & B (rows) then inside of B is C & D. I need update & submit a form in D. How would I go about selecthing this to use in my javascript

Answer (score 0):

If it's in your first frame, you could do the following:

```
window.frames[0].document.formname.fieldname.value
```